# How can I make the MasterDetailPage faster on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have a master detail page on xamarin cross-platform but the navigation on Android is very slow

Instead of sliding to hide the menu it just make a flash and disappear How can I make it look in a faster way?

I also try with the example of https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/
  but is the same thing it continues in slow way on android

I have my masterdetail page xaml

and this is the "MASTER" MENU   XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Injoy.MasterPage"
             Padding="0,50,0,0"
             Title="Menú"
             BackgroundColor="#dcdb26">


    <ContentPage.Content>

        <RelativeLayout>
            <Image Aspect="Fill" Source="fondoAmarilloI.png"/>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" >
                <Image Source="unnamed.png" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="80"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" >
                    <Button x:Name="CalendarBtn" Text="Calendario" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    <Button x:Name="ProfileBtn" Text="Perfil" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    <Button x:Name="PlanBtn" Text="Arma Tu Plan" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    <Button x:Name="PayBtn" Text="Pago" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    <Button x:Name="LogoutBtn" Text="Cerrar Sesión" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    <!--<ListView x:Name="listView" RowHeight="50" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label x:Name="hide" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        <Label Text="     " />
                                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" />
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="24" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource2}" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>-->
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

CODE BEHIND two examples of the buttons

```
  private void PlanBtnClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.mainPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new AddPlan());
        this.mainPage.IsPresented = false;
    }

    private void LogOutBtnClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.mainPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new LogOut());
        this.mainPage.IsPresented = false;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "make it faster"? How long does it take at the moment? And how fast should do you want it to be?

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
private async Task PlanBtnClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mainPage.IsPresented = false;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Task.Delay(300).Wait();
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            mainPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new AddPlan());
        });
    });
}

private async Task LogOutBtnClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mainPage.IsPresented = false;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Task.Delay(300).Wait();
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            mainPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new LogOut());
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i found solution, especially for users of VS2015.
working with MasterDetailPage i faced the following problems:

1. delay is bad code, you never know, how fast the animation really is.
2. when changing `IsPresented` to `false`, the animation starts and it concurrents with popToRootAsync => this results to lag of animation, when masterPage menu is closing.
3. otherwise you have to pick, what you will do first: close menu or draw a new page (this is still unsolved, but animates acceptable)
4. xamarin.forms has a [bug](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2740) , fixed only in version 3.2.0, which leads to random app crashes while picking pages.
5. you can't get xamarin.forms 3+ without VS2017

the solution is: first, we add a new page before the current one, then pop it up and handle `Appearing` event.

```
var root = Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack[0];
MasterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
if (item.Page == root)
{
    IsPresented = false;
}
else
{
    Detail.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(INSERT_YOUR_NEW_PAGE_HERE, root);
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        await Detail.Navigation.PopToRootAsync(false);
    });
    if(null != item.Page)
    item.Page.Appearing += CloseMenuEvent;
}
```

finally, as you catch the event, close the menu and release handler (or it will be called multiple times, if you store the page)

```
private void CloseMenuEvent(object o, EventArgs args)
{
    IsPresented = false;
    var stack = Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack;
    if ( null != stack && stack.Count > 0 )
        Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack[0].Appearing -= CloseMenuEvent;
}
```

store your page (marked as `INSERT_YOUR_NEW_PAGE_HERE` in code), if you want the animation to be quick.

UPD: this does not solve app crashes, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385156/9961057) helped a lot.
after i added `Dispose` overload method to `ListViewRenderer`, crashes stopped.
this has some correlation with scrolling listview and selecting a new page at the same time.